# 2 Domains into common URL for looks and Google Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics

Not sure if I worded the title correctly for what I would like to do, but here goes.

We have 2 domains one that services the national sales and manufacturing, the other serves installations in one state only. The (Sales) domain wants the Google scores for the (Install) domain [long time on site, virtually no bounce,  and pages served] to be a part of the (Sales) domain Google analytic's stats and Search Engine rankings.

One domain is Cold Fusion / Flash Desktop only - (Sales) the other is ASP.Net C# mobile friendly responsive - (Install). They are also 2 different departments and politics.

I have been asked, only for the benefit of SEO and Google Analytic's to place the ASP responsive website under the sales domain.

I am hoping to avoid attempting to migrate and publish under the (Sales) domain and keep the (Install) domain as is. We have other applications that use the directory structure of the (Install) domain for FTP and file storage for front facing customer image retrieval.

So the question is, can I leave the install website where it is and point to it under the sales domain and make it so that the users and more importantly Google sees it as one continuous domain? What do I need to do?

TIA

Comment: I'm rather sure that the SEO part of that question is off-topic for SO (which is concerned with programming questions) and should better be asked on webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics is not bothered with domain names and will track data to a property no matter where the tracking calls come from, so part of the solution is to install the same tracking code with the same UAID on both domains. However without some more preparation visits that span both domains will not appear as continuous visit, instead a new session will be started if the user switches from one domain to another. To prevent this you need to [configure your code for cross-domain tracking](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en).

Google Analytics stitches pageviews into sessions by the use of a clientid which is stored in a cookie. Pageviews that have the same clientid as per the _ga cookie and happen within a certain timeframe will be aggregated into (a session expires after 30min of inactivity or 500 interactions). Outside that timeframe the user will appear as known user with multiple sessions. The user session is also restarted when the traffic source changes.

Since the clientid is stored in a cookie and cookies are domain specific changes in the domain will start a new session. To prevent this from happening you can link multiple domains. Linked domains will look at incoming hits for a parameter (_ga) that contains a clientid. If the parameter is present they will use it to identify a visit (i.e. in the backend GA will connect this to the visits on the other domain). To make this work you need to append the _ga parameter on all links and forms that lead to the other domain.  Google provides the "autolinker" GA plugin that automatically adds the _ga parameter to outgoing links to the other domain.

That was a short rundown how cross-domain tracking works, for the actual implementation I would refer you to the [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en) (which I  think is rather good).

The SEO part of your question is not really on-topic I think. If both domains had the same content you could set one of them as "preferred domain" in the Google search console, but I'm not sure how this  will affect sites that are in fact different.

Comment: AWESOME! FWIW the SEO part was for clarity of desired end result outcome and why I need to do this, not so much as to how do I do the SEO aspects ;~) . You answered the question fantastically! Thanks for the links, I have some reading to do.